# Strip trailing spaces from variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

Windows 10
Batch File

Trying to strip trailing spaces from variable. Here's what I have so far...

```
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims= " %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_VideoController Get Name^,DriverVersion^|FindStr /I "Intel"') Do @Set GFXNAM=%%B&SetGFXVER=%%A
```

With that, I get the two variables populated correctly as such...

GFXNAM=[Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630          ]
GFXVER=[27.20.100.9316]
*(brackets have been added to visualize trailing spaces in the variables)*

However, I need a way to trim those trailing spaces at the end of the GFXNAM variable. Unfortunately, due to the parenthesis within the GFXNAM variable value, I have been unable to use a for loop along with variable manipulation along the lines of...

```
(set NEWGFXNAM=%GFXNAM:~0,-1%)
```

It fails due to those lovely poison characters. All I need to do is to be able to strip those trailing spaces from that GFXNAM variable. It shouldn't be this difficult, but I just can't see it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use table output for your WMIC command. Take a look at the options available using the `/Format` option, i.e. `/Format:List`, `/Format:CSV`, `/Format:MOF`.

Comment: Well, that would work perfectly if I were using PowerShell instead of a batch file. (lol)

Comment: I use them in almost all of my WMIC batch scripts, most often MOF, _and guess what, all of mine work perfectly_.

Comment: Apologies, my comment wasn't meant to be negative or incorrect.

Comment: When I modify the code to [ wmic path win32_videocontroller get name,driverversion /format:list|findstr /i "intel" ] I only get a result of [ name=Intel(R) UHD Graphics 640 ] and nothing about the version number. Thx again.

Comment: That is because `list` will output each result in a different line, so `findstr` will only match the line containing the string `Intel`! You do not need to use `findstr.exe` for this anyhow, WMI already allows for WQL queries, so use that to SELECT only `Name`'s beginning with the string `Intel` instead. If nothing else it's more efficient to filter higher up the process than later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example using my comment, and based upon only having one Intel graphics card in your PC:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "GFXNam="
Set "GFXVer="
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path
 Win32_VideoController Where "Name Like 'Intel%%'" Get Name^, DriverVersion
 /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do If Not Defined GFXVer (Set "GFXVer=%%G"
) Else Set "GFXNam=%%G"
Set GFX 2>NUL
Pause
```

If you want to check that it did correctly define the variables, you can replace `Set GFX 2>NUL` with `If Defined GFXVer If Defined GFXNam Echo Name: [%GFXNam%], Version: [%GFXVer%]`.